# Calculated column in a dataGrid bound with a ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm building a WPF - MVVM application. I have a dataGrid bound with a ObservableCollection.

In this collection I have a column Quantity,a column Price/MOQ and a column Total that has to be logicaly equal to Quantity * Price = Total.

So each time I add a row and fill Quantity and Price, Total column has to be calculated.

How can I do that?

## **View**

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridInvoice" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AddingNewItem="dataGridInvoice_AddingNewItem">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="SuppNb" Binding="{Binding suppInvNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shop" Binding="{Binding shop, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding date, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Supplier" Binding="{Binding supplier, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Ref Supplier"
                                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Products, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource supplier}}"
                                                    DisplayMemberPath="refsup" 
                                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding refSupp}" 
                                                    SelectedValuePath="refsup"
                                                    Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Unit"
                                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource unit}}"
                                                    DisplayMemberPath="unit1" 
                                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding unit}" 
                                                    SelectedValuePath="idunit"
                                                    Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding quantity, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prix/MOQ" Binding="{Binding unitPrice, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Price" Binding="{Binding totalPrice, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

### **ViewModel**

```
public class InvoiceViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Context ctx = new Context();
    public InvoiceViewModel()
    {
        Get(false);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Invoice> collection;
    public ObservableCollection<Invoice> Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return collection;
        }
        set
        {
            collection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
        }
    }

    private Invoice _selected;
    public Invoice Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return _selected;
        }
        set
        {
            _selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }

    private void Get(bool loadDataFirst)
    {
        if(loadDataFirst)
            ctx.Invoices.Load();
        Collection = ctx.Invoices.Local;
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void Delete()
    {
        var id = Selected;
        var invoice = (from i in ctx.Invoices
                       where i.idInvoice == id.idInvoice
                       select i).SingleOrDefault();
        Collection.Remove(invoice);
    }

    private Invoice _currentItem;
    public Invoice CurrentItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        }
    }

    #region "Command"

    private ICommand saveCommand;
    private ICommand removeCommand;

    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return saveCommand ?? (saveCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.Save(), p => this.CanSave()));
        }
    }
    private bool CanSave()
    {
        return true;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

## **Model**

```
public partial class Invoice
    {
        public int idInvoice { get; set; }
        public string invNumber { get; set; }
        public string suppInvNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> supplier { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> shop { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> date { get; set; }
        public string refSupp { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> quantity { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> unitPrice { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> totalPrice { get; set; }

        public virtual foodSupplier foodSupplier { get; set; }
        public virtual shop shop1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: 2 comments about your question. First, the datagrid ItemsSource binding doesn't add up. Isn't it should be the "Collection" ObservableCollection ? Second, when you try to bind something like "Binding="{Binding foodSupplier.supplier}" ... that's a bit if volation of MVVM pattern. See, the idea is decoupling the xmal and the ViewModel implementation as much as possible. Try to bind everything to ViewModel's property instead of Property return's inner logic.

Comment: Oh by the way, i cannot see why u can't get why you'll have problem to have your calculated column for your Grid. Is that your "Invoice" (which .. you didn't post in your question) class doesn't implement the "totalPrice" property ?

Comment: You are right, I showed the wrong view.

Comment: Post your `Invoice` class.

Comment: It's a new Invoice, the user has to fill it. So, to do it faster, I need to calculate this totalPrice column. But, I'm thinking about delete this column in the database, because I don't really need it as long as I calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cantinou,

I see two ways :

1. Change the Invoice class so that it raises events

   public partial class Invoice : ViewModelBase
   {
       // ....
       private Nullable quantity;

   ```
   public Nullable<decimal> Quantity
   {
       get { return quantity; }
       set
       {
           quantity = value;
           base.OnPropertyChanged();
           if (quantity.HasValue && unitPrice.HasValue)
               TotalPrice = quantity * unitPrice;
       }
   }
   private Nullable<decimal> unitPrice;

   public Nullable<decimal> UnitPrice
   {
       get { return unitPrice; }
       set
       {
           unitPrice = value;
           base.OnPropertyChanged();
           if (quantity.HasValue && unitPrice.HasValue)
               TotalPrice = quantity * unitPrice;
       }
   }
   private Nullable<decimal> totalPrice;

   public Nullable<decimal> TotalPrice
   {
       get { return totalPrice; }
       set
       {
           totalPrice = value;
           base.OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Put some code in your GUI to detect end of edition and make product. I think it 's not the responsability of the view to compute prices,... but technically it is possible.

   ```
   private void DataGridInvoiceRowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit) {
           Invoice invoice = e.Row.DataContext as Invoice;
           // update Invoice object if needed
           if (invoice != null)
           {
               // ....
           }
       }
   }
   private void DataGridInvoiceCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
   {
      // ...
   }
   ```

Regards

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel. I am using Entity Framework 6.0 to get my data. And after changing my model, I get this error when I'm running the app:     Unable to find assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: Did you change the property names ? It may affect your data access. If you changed the property names, try in a first step not to modify the names and keep your project working. If you have some existing data, and want to change the property names,you could consider using the PowerShell scripts : enable-migrations, Add-Migration, ... But I am not sure it 's the current problem

Comment: Works fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So what was the problem with EF6 ?